# MariaDB maintain key order in COLUMN_CREATE

Tags: mariadb-10.3

I am using a 10.3.11 table with the following structure

```
MariaDB> desc MetaData;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| meta_data_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| foreign_id   | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| api_name     | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| index1       | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| index2       | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| index3       | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| index4       | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meta_data    | blob             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The MetaData contains dynamic columns created using

```
INSERT INTO MetaData(meta_data) VALUES(COLUMN_CREATE('CallID', 'as','field1','value1','field3','value2','field2', 'value3','field4','value4
'));
```

The indexes are required because, as its names suggests, the dynamic column names can conform to any naming convention. index1 stores the value of the first dynamic column etc. and is indexed for ease of searching.

The problem is that COLUMN_CREATE appears to reorder the column name keys alphabetically, meaning that in the above example field2 is put in front of field3 and hence gives this.

```
MariaDB > select column_json(meta_data) from MetaData;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| column_json(meta_data)                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"CallID":"as","field1":"value1","field2":"value3","field3":"value2","field4":"value4"} |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This means that a search in index2 or index3 will not return the correct data. Is it possible to retain the column order or do I need to rethink the strategy by reordering the columns and index values before inserting into the table?

```
CREATE TABLE `MetaData` (
  `meta_data_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foreign_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `api_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `index1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `index2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `index3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `index4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_data` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_data_id`),
  KEY `foreign_id` (`foreign_id`),
  KEY `index1` (`index1`),
  KEY `index2` (`index2`),
  KEY `index3` (`index3`),
  KEY `index4` (`index4`),
  KEY `api_name` (`api_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: *table with the following structure* Show `SHOW CREATE TABLE MetaData` output instead. *COLUMN_CREATE appears to reorder the column name keys alphabetically* This behavior do not interfere with the documentation. Use the function in the form where fields numbers, not names, are set.

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. Unfortunately it is a requirement that human readable names are required for the column names so that the client can indentify the metadata when they retrieve it.

Comment: MariaDB appears to reorder the keys in COLUMN_CREATE first by key length then alphabetically.

So

{"Company": "company test", "Name": "John Smith", "Notes": "note note note"}

is stored as

{"Name":"John Smith","Notes":"note note note","Company":"company test"}

as Name and Notes have less characters than Company.

I think that I will need to accept this and adjust the indexing accordingly.